# JQueryMobile 1.4 popup not opening after transition to the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear"

The page is called sorting.php

The main link in each list item is for example sorting.php?parent=1

The gear icon (split icon) opens #popup which is a data-role="popup" id="popup"

My problem is that the popup opens correctly the first time I open sorting.php, but after clicking a list item an transitioning to sorting.php?parent=1, the popup does not open.

The URL bar in the browser just shows **"sorting.php?parent=1#&ui-state=dialog"** when I click on the gear icon, but nothing happens. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>P1</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">

<script src="res/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script> $(document).on("mobileinit", function () { $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false; }); </script>
<script src="res/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo" data-overlay-theme="e">

<div data-role="popup" id="popup">
<ul data-role="listview" data-count-theme="c" data-inset="true">
    <li class="custom-li">
        <div data-role="collapsible" class="custom-collapsible" data-iconpos="right">
            <h3>Editar</h3> 
            <p>Formulario</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="custom-bottom-li"><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Crear Hijo</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b"><h1>P1</h1></div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true">

<?php
require_once("res/mysql/mysql-connect.php");
if(isset($_GET["parent"])) 
    $where = " WHERE sorting_parent_id =". $_GET["parent"];
else
    $where = " WHERE sorting_parent_id =0";

if ($res_sorting_padres = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM sorting".$where)) 
{
    while ($fila = $res_sorting_padres->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $r1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(sorting_id) from sorting where sorting_parent_id =".$fila['sorting_id']);
        $cuenta = $r1->fetch_row();
        $enlace = '';
        if ($cuenta[0] > 0) $enlace = "sorting.php?parent=".$fila['sorting_id'];
        echo '<li><a href="'.$enlace.'"><p>'.$fila['sorting_description'].'</p><span class="ui-li-count">'.$cuenta[0].'</span></a>';
        echo '<a href="#popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade">Opciones</a></li>';
    }
    $res_sorting_padres->close();   
}
else
{
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
?>
</ul>
</div>  
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c"><h1>Footer Text</h1></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: i'm not sure whether this would work, but just give it a try. in `<head>` after jQuery.js and before jQM.js add this `$(document).on("mobileinit", function () { $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false; });` this will disable hash change in URL bar.

Comment: Don't know if I did put the "mobileinit" function correctly, but this hasn't worked. I've pasted my code. Thanks for helping guys